# Combining multiple regression formulas

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regularization

The normal equation for ordinary least squares regression is as follows:

$$
\hat{w} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
$$

but this gives a model that underfits. One way to counter underfitting is to use [locally weighted linear regression](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume4/cohn96a-html/node7.html) using a Gaussian kernel. The formula goes as follows:

$$
\hat{w} = (X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWy
$$

where W is a diagonal matrix of weights. The closer an unknown point $x$ is to example $i$ in the training set, the higher the value for $W[i,i]$. So instead of getting a straight line, line can now be curvy depending on the size of the kernel.

and finally, there's [ridge regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) that shrinks the regression weights to avoid overfitting. The formula goes as:

$$
\hat{w} = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty
$$

My question is: can equations 2 and 3 be combined to get the best of both the worlds? To have a line that isn't straight but also doesn't overfit the data??

$$
\hat{w} = (X^TWX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^TWy
$$

Comment: I don't see where your assertion  "this gives a model that underfits" comes from? also what do you mean with "to have a line that isn't straight"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic model behind the first equation is

$$ y =X\beta + \epsilon $$

with $\epsilon$ a sample out of multivariate normal $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 I)$. Assuming this model holds, then the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE) of $\beta$ is the OLS:

$$ \hat\beta = (X^tX)^{-1}X^ty $$

Now, if you believe that your error is **not homoscedastic** so that for some reason you think that $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$ for some covariance matrix $\Sigma$ then what you can do is consider the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$: $\Sigma=LL^t$ you can then write:

$$ y =X\beta + L \epsilon' $$

with $\epsilon'\sim \mathcal N(0,I)$. With $\Sigma$ positive definite, $L$ is invertible, and you can write

$$ L^{-1}y = L^{-1}X\beta + \epsilon' $$

then you're back in the first scenario, with the BLUE being $\hat\beta = (X^t\Omega X)X^t \Omega y$ with $\Omega=\Sigma^{-1}=(LL^t)^{-1}=L^{-t}L^{-1}$.

If you can approximate the inverse of the covariance matrix (the $\Omega$) for example with a diagonal matrix, you're in the second scenario you're referring to.

Now, it's not hard to link this with Ridge regression, with homoscedastic errors, you regularize with

$$ \min_\beta \|X\beta - y\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\beta\|_2^2 $$

and the answer is, as you wrote: $\hat\beta_R = (X^t X+\lambda I)^{-1}X^t y$.

Let's do exactly the same thing after transforming the data with the square root $L^{-1}$ of $\Omega=L^{-t}L^{-1}$ (or an approximation):

$$ \min_\beta \| L^{-1}X\beta - L^{-1} y\|_2^2 + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2 $$

just rewrite $X'=\Omega X$ and $y'=\Omega y$, the problem is then the same than in the Ridge regression case and therefore, indeed, the solution is the "combination":

$$\hat\beta_R' = (X^t\Omega X+\lambda I)^{-1}X^t \Omega y. $$